# r - selecting dataframe columns works differently in Rscript and Rstudio

Tags: r, dataframe, rscript, rstudio-server

I have a very curious question.

I developed a script (say script1) through Rstudio, than sourced it in another script (say script2). This second script is launched via Rscript.

Inside script1 there's this line:

```
df_clean<-df[which(df$sum==0),c(2:7)]
```

Look at **c(2:7)**; as far as I know, I'm just filtering columns.

Here comes the strange part. Let's say that df columns are

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h
```

When I run script1 line by line, I get columns

```
b, c, d, e, f, g
```

but when I run

```
./script2
```

(which sources script1 and then run my code) I get all shifted by one position

```
c, d, e, f, g, h
```

I solved it filtering by column name, but why is this happening?
The 'source' command I use is

```
source("script1.R", echo=TRUE, max.deparse.length=10000, encoding="UTF-8")
```

Also, I'm not on different machines. It's all in the same place.

I'm not an R-hero so maybe this is a silly question...help me growing ;-)

Comment: Are you entirely sure both scripts run the same code an receive the same data as input?

Comment: @tobiasegli_te script1 is always the same, what changes is only the way I execute it. Input also is the same, for sure. Using names to filter columns gives me the same result, both in Rstudio and Rscript

Comment: Is script2 also a R-script and do you pass any arguments to script1?

Comment: @tobiasegli_te yes, both scripts are R-script. script1 has no arguments passed.

Comment: Can you provide the source of the scripts?

Comment: @Stereo unfortunately the scripts are property of my company. Also, they are very long and complicated; the structure anyway is the one provided in the question. The point here is that I'm running exactly the same piece of code, with same inputs in the same environment. The only difference is the way I run it. This is confirmed by the fact that filtering columns by name, I get the same output.

Comment: Have you printed the head of df when run from script1 vs. script2? My guess is that the input is getting read into df slightly differently when executed from script1 vs script2.

Comment: @ercaran, is there some unicode in your script? Maybe something is happening with column names between Rscript an Rstudio. Can you give us some background on the versions of R that you are using as well as Rstudio?

Comment: @emilliman5 good suggestion, thanks. Unfortunately there are no differences :-(

Comment: @Stereo I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you mean some unicode char like 0008 for backspace, then no. Rstudio 0.99.484
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) "Fire Safety"

Comment: look at your `.Rprofile` files, also compare output of `sessionInfo()` in Rstudio and in the script right before the `source` line.